# A limit theorem for non-independent variables

Tags: probability, law-of-large-numbers

Let $X_n$ be a sequence of identically distributed (e.g., [binomial](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/43078/13538) $B(1,1/2)$) random variables which are *not* [independent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)) (say, for any $n$ and $m$, $corr(X_n,X_m)=c>0$).

What can be said about the limit of their mean $\frac{1}{N}\sum_n X_n$?

Motivation: a reason price variations assumed to be [Gaussian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) is that they are composed by allegedly independent actions of many traders. However, in reality the traders are not independent, because, e.g., they all read the same news.

Comment: What kind of limit interests you?

Comment: any limit is fine

Comment: Actually, it's more related to law of large numbers than central limit theorem.

Comment: Do you need limit laws for [exchangeable random variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_random_variables)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think little or nothing can be said with no more assumptions than stated.  With more assumptions about the dependence among the $X_n$, some limit theorems are proved in [this paper](http://www.d.umn.edu/~yqi/mydownload/08letter.pdf).